# inside putty when i ask to see all the directories in my public_html folder it only returns 2 folders

Tags: linux, shell, unix, putty

[image]I hope this isn't the stupidest question ever but i know there is more then two folders inside public_html.

I've tried the cmd's:

```
ls

ls -R

ls -al

ls -d */
```

Is there a permission issue that i'm struggling with and that's the reason i can't see the other directories. As you can tell i'm very new inside the shell/unix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know there is more than two folder?

Comment: Well, when i look at the folder structure in my IDE or in an FTP client there is loads more.

Comment: when you are login using FTP are you using same credential? I can see you logged in in the shell using 'root' user. or Can you be more specific what others folder you see?

Comment: I'm using different credentials when i login through my IDE or FTP.

Comment: I think thats why you don't see other files. try using same credential and see.

Comment: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) .... I'm using pagaent.. so i need to create another/seperate key? i have puttygen loaded.

Comment: Yes.You need to create another key if it wasn't added before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68845/discussion-between-rad-and-md-al-amin).

Comment: I just created a new key in putty gen but i'm still getting that error message
any idea?

Comment: not really a programming question. should migrate this to serverfault or superuser maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're logged into a different account then ~/public_html will be a different directory

`~` denotes the home directory, and every user has their own home directory.

i.e.
`/home/user1/public_html` will look like `~/public_html` when logged in as user1

and
`/home/user2/public_html` will look the same `~/public_html` when logged in as user2

Btw root is special and their home directory is /root/ rather than /home/root/

you can use the command `pwd` to show the full path of where you are.

**Edit - Additional info:**
root has access to all files in the system. So as user root, you could go to any of the `/home/<username>` directories.
root can become any of the users on the system by using the [su](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) command `su <username>`

Comment: When i logged back in and used the cmd pwd. it returned /root and then i changed directories to public_html and used the cmd pwd and it basically just returned /root/public_html. I'm just confused to where i'm located because i don't see any other public html folders except the main one with all the folders and data. and of course in this case it doesn't contain all the folders and data.

Comment: As root on the remote host, do this: `su - foo` where "foo" is the ftp username. Then `cd public_html`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I just realized i needed to back up a few directories. CD ..  CD ..  a few times. Thanks again!